# How get value of a textarea and check it whether it empty or not

Tags: javascript, html

I have created `textarea` using `simpleMde` but now I couldn't get the value and check it whether it is empty or not

```js
var message = document.getElementById("simpleMde").value;
console.log(message);
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="simpleMde" name="message"></textarea>
```

It shows an empty string only.

Comment: Plz, include your code.

Comment: Yes sorry this is my first time

Comment: You want the value on click or every time it's typed?

Comment: Yes like this is a part of a form and i want to check whether it is empty or not...

Comment: I have added the answer!

Answer (score 2):

In this, it will check every time you press the button if the `textarea` is empty or not

You can do this:

```js
const message = document.getElementById("simpleMde");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function onClick() {
  if (message.value !== "") {
    console.log(message.value);
  } else {
    console.log("Message can not be empty! ");
  }
}

btn.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" id="simpleMde" name="message"></textarea>
<button id="btn">Submit Message</button>
```

Comment: Noo, this is also no working...It is not a simple textarea guys...It is a textarea similar to the textarea of stackoverflow with all the text editor buttons, Try to copy the id name and search it and see it u might get an idea.

Comment: @Karan_raj You have asked "***How get value of a textarea and check it whether it empty or not***".

Comment: @Karan_raj Plz share your code till now in the textarea

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like that you are getting the value the instant the code loads. Since the textarea is initially empty, that will log an empty string. However, you can add an event listener to listen for user input in the textarea, and take your action from then on.

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector("textarea")
textarea.addEventListener("input", evt => {
  console.clear()
  console.log(evt.target.value);
})
```

```html
<label>Message</label><br>
<textarea class="form-control" id="simpleMde" name="message"></textarea>
```

In this example, every time you provide an input inside the textarea, the input event fires. Inside the event listener, you can see that the console is cleared, and the new value is logged.

Comment: It is also logging empty strings.

Comment: It is working for me. Are you sure you have javascript enabled?

Comment: If so, could you also provide me with the browser you are using? I might be able to troubleshoot it better that way.

Comment: If you press enter in the textarea you will see it being logged but technically its empty.

Comment: I know how to fix it, I was just letting you know.

Comment: Not sure what you're on, but that should not be the case - it should fire every time a key is pressed and something shows up on the textbox (but not for control, escape, etc. keys).

Comment: Press enter in the textbox.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. The enter key is still an input, so it fires the event listener. If you would like to disable that, then simply adapt the code with an if statement checking if the new input is a `\n` (new line).

Comment: Noo guys this is not working...It return an error - Uncaught TypeError: message.addEventListener is not a function